# How to send listview items username ,email and address to next activity onItemClick in android

Tags: android, xml

I need to create a login App where i have to show only user names in listview on successful login authentication and onItemClick of usernames listview , i have to show user details like name, email and address in textview on another activity. All user details should be parsed from an Xml file.

Basically, I have three activities that is
1. Login.java 
2. Users.java
3. UserDetails.java

However, I have send usernames from (Users.java) listview to userdetails(on Textview).
Now , i need to send email, address to (UserDetails) activity.
The thing is that Email and address is not in (Users.java) listview where i have only showing user names.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

here is my Users.java

```
public class Users extends Activity {

ListView myList ;
List<String> fillUsers;
List<String> fillemail;
List<String> fillphone;
List<String> fillplace;
List<String> titles;
List<String> link1;

//private List<Map<String, Object>> data;
private ListView listView = null;

private List<com.example.firstapp.Message> messages;

static final String KEY_FNAME = "fname";
static final String KEY_LNAME = "lname";
static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
static final String KEY_PLACE = "place";
List headlines;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_users);

    new MyAsyncTask().execute();

 }


private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

       final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

     final ArrayAdapter<String>  listAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(Users.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fillUsers); 

        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


    try{
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                String selectedFromList =(String) (listView.getItemAtPosition(position));

                System.out.println("Testing 006: "+fillemail+fillphone+fillplace);

                 System.out.println("Testing 008: "+selectedFromList);

                 Intent in = new Intent(Users.this,UserDetails.class);

                 System.out.println("Testing 009: ");


                 Bundle myBundle = new Bundle(); //create a Bundle
                 myBundle.putString("username",selectedFromList);
                 myBundle.putInt("userid",1234);
                 System.out.println("Testing 010: ");

                 in.putExtras(myBundle); //PUT THE Bundle you created in the Intent
                 startActivityForResult(in, 0);
                 System.out.println("Testing 010: ");

                }
             });
        }catch(Exception ex){

           System.out.println("On item click : 0070"+ex.toString());
           System.out.println("On item click : 0080"+ex.getStackTrace().toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Users.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

       // your network operation

        loadFeed();

      return (null);
    }


    public void loadFeed(){

        try{

            BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser();
            messages = parser.parse();
              Log.e("check=","yes");
              List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
              HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


              int count=0;
              for (com.example.firstapp.Message msg : messages){
                    count++;
              }

               fillUsers = new ArrayList<String>(count);
               fillemail = new ArrayList<String>(count);
               fillphone = new ArrayList<String>(count);
               fillplace = new ArrayList<String>(count);

            for (com.example.firstapp.Message msg : messages){


                fillUsers.add(msg.getFname()+" "+msg.getLname());
                fillemail.add(msg.getEmail());
                fillphone.add(msg.getPhone());
                fillplace.add(msg.getPlace());

                System.out.println("OOOOOOOOOOOO "+fillemail.toString());



              }
                return;
            } catch (Throwable t){
            Log.e("AndroidNews",t.getMessage(),t);

            t.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: your question is not clear enough. if you want to send information to the details activity you can send the data as Intent.Putexta to the new activity.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted, can you point out the error you are getting or what you notice when debugging?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse XML and pass parsed information to the next Activity by using [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

For example,

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("UserName","Color");
startActivity(mIntent);
```

I think this information is more than enough as per your information provided in question.

### Update:

Based on the code, i would suggest you below points:

1. Why to create different List, here i would say it would be difficult to manage while inserting/deleting data, lets say i want to delete one record, now as per your code you have to delete from every List, right? Yes it is. So instead of creating different list, you can create add Object inside list something like `ArrayList<Student>`
2. Now, the point comes about passing dynamic data(your word), if you follow 1st point then you can directly pass whole object to the second activity or wherever else you want. FYI, you can get clicked object from ArrayList by clicked position.

Comment: Thanks, but how to send dynamic value email, address to another activity. The thing is Email and address is not in listview where i am only showing user names.

Comment: @user1788241 i would be sending code if you send me $5000 :) My dear without trying anything how can one help you out?

Answer (score 0):

put below code in onItemClickListener..

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("name", "Name");
i.putExtra("email", "Email");
i.putExtra("address", "Address");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to send dynamic value email, address to another activity.The thing is Email and address is not in listview(Users.java) where i am only showing user names.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it.

1) Create a pojo class with static variables and use them in your next activity.

```
public class MyClass{
 public static  String varaible1;
 public static  String varaible2;
 public static  int varaible3;
 public static  List myList;
}
```

2) Create your own application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

 private  String varaible1;
 private String varaible2;
 private int varaible3;
 private List myList;
 publid getter, setter methods
}
```

in your activity use

```
MyApplication  myApplication =(MyApplication)getApplication();

myApplication.getVaraible1();
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"  
         android:name="MyApplication">
```